# Issues with my Crawl Spider and Pagination. Only Value from the First Page being Extracted

Tags: pagination, web-scraping, scrapy

My task is to take stock updates from one of my suppliers : www.sportsshoes.com .

The issue I am facing is that despite the Crawl Spider visiting each page of a category page it only gives returns data from the first page. This also is the case if I try and scrape each page independently i.e even if I assign it to scrape the third page of the category it only returns results from the first page.

My Code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from sportshoes.items import SportshoesItem
import urlparse 
from scrapy.http.request import Request


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "tennis"
  allowed_domains = ["sportsshoes.com"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.sportsshoes.com/products/shoe/tennis/",
                "http://www.sportsshoes.com/products/shoe/tennis#page=2",
                "http://www.sportsshoes.com/products/shoe/tennis#page=3"]

  rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="product-detail"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True,),)

  def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//html")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
      item = SportshoesItem()
      item ["productname"] = titles.select("//h1[@id='product_title']/span/text()").extract()
      item ["Size"] = titles.select('//option[@class="sizeOption"]/text()').extract()
      item ["SKU"] = titles.select("//div[@id='product_ref']/strong/text()").extract()

      items.append(item)
      return(items)
```

PS : I had used this method too  :

```
  rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="paginator"]',)), follow= True),
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="hproduct product"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),)
```

Answer (score 1):

Those `#page=2` and `#page=3` links are considered to be the same page by Scrapy. For scrapy, they're interpreted as in-page named anchor references. So they're not downloaded twice.

They mean something in the browser though, with the help of some Javascript.

When you inspect what happens in your browser's Inspect/Developer tool when you click on "Next" pages links, you'll notice AJAX calls to `http://www.sportsshoes.com/ajax/products/search.php` as HTTP POST requests, and with parameters similar to the following:

```
page:3
search-option[show]:20
search-option[sort]:relevency
q:
na:YTowOnt9
sa:YToyOntpOjA7YToyOntzOjM6ImtleSI7czoxMzoicHJvZHVjdF9jbGFzcyI7czo2OiJ2YWx1ZTEiO3M6NDoic2hvZSI7fWk6MTthOjI6e3M6Mzoia2V5IjtzOjU6InNwb3J0IjtzOjY6InZhbHVlMSI7czo2OiJ0ZW5uaXMiO319
aav:YTowOnt9
layout:undefined
```

The responses to these AJAX calls are XML documents embedding the HTML containing pages from next pages, that will end up replacing the first page products.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response success="true">
    <message>success</message>
    <value key="html"><![CDATA[<div id="extra-data" data-extra-na="YTowOnt9"...
```

You have to emulate these AJAX call to get the data for all the pages. Note that these POST requests contain a special header: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

To tell scrapy to send POST requests, you can use the ["method" parameter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.method) when creating `Requests` objects.